# Visual Studio Does Not Generate .exe File

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I code an C++ program by VS 2022 but an error occurred when I tried to run it. I've built it successfully. I couldn't find any .exe file in 'debug' after I built it. It shows ('System can't find file'.)

Comment: Check the logs of your virus scanner.

Comment: If there's no executable file then either you have an error which you haven't noticed (please copy-paste the full build output into the question), or the executable is placed somewhere else (please check your configuration, and make sure you build the `Debug` target). Or, your anti-virus stepped in, please check its logs.

Comment: Veirfy if in Build > Batch Build your configuration is checked. If ok, report any error message during the build.

Answer (score 2):

There might be something wrong with your configuration.
You mention the build has been successful. In that case, the "output" window, when you choose "Show output from:", and there you have chosen "Build", that output should contain a line, containing the two characters `->`. Those characters clearly show where your application has been built, like in this example:

```
App.Server -> C:\Whatever_Directory\App.Server.dll
```

Please check that directory. In case your compilation result is not there, it has been moved or deleted, most possibly by:

- a post-Build build event: check your project's properties, "Build Events"
- a virusscanner.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

The files can be complied outside of the project folder.

```
Right click your project > Open Folder in File Explorer > Navigate back one folder > x64 or x86 > Then you will see Debug or Release depending on what you have complied as.
```

Alternatively, the complier tells you the directory path where it has compiled to in the output window.